Feature Flagging in Databricks with DevOps
Has anyone managed to get a working process between DevOps and Databricks working?
The only way I can think of making it work is using a file as a "control table" that is updated as part of the release process, a bit like a config file.

Hi @Lynchie, Good day to you. Have you got a chance to check my answer to authenticate against a service principal in databricks CLI commands integrated in pipelines? Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. Thx and have a lovely weekend.

Assuming you would expect to setup a working process between Azure DevOps and Databricks to use the agent jobs of Azure Pipelines to manage/deploy to a Databricks instance, you may leverage the Databricks CLI tool installed during the pipeline run and authenticate against a service principal to access your workspace.
Here is a sample script that runs in pipelines.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: |
    pip install databricks-cli

    # Unique resource ID for the Azure Databricks service, which is 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d
    # Login and get access token for the service principal via Azure CLI
    # az login --service-principal --username $(ApplicationId) --password $(ClientSecret) --tenant $(TenantId)
    # ACCESS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d --query accessToken --output tsv)

    # Use API to get AAD token for the service principal to access Databricks
    ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/$(TenantId)/oauth2/v2.0/token \
    -d "client_id=$(ApplicationId)" \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
    -d "scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default" \
    -d "client_secret=$(ClientSecret)" | jq -r '.access_token'
    )

    # Set databricks environment variables for authentication
    export DATABRICKS_HOST=https://adb-$(DatabricksInstance).azuredatabricks.net/
    export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=$ACCESS_TOKEN

    # Generate databricks configuration file for authentication
    # export DATABRICKS_CONFIG_FILE=".databrickscfg"
    # echo "[DEFAULT]" > .databrickscfg
    # echo "host = $DATABRICKS_HOST" >> .databrickscfg
    # echo "token = $ACCESS_TOKEN" >> .databrickscfg

    # List objects in a workspace
    databricks workspace list --absolute --long --id /Shared



In addition, there are 3rd-party marketplace extensions such as Databricks Script Deployment Task by Data Thirst for databricks deployment. You may review if the functions in the extensions can meet your requirements.
Besides, it is advisable to go through the document of CI/CD on Azure Databricks, which includes not only the workflow in Azure DevOps but also other automation tools.
